# Workaround for webbrowsers buffering live webm streams and introducing a delay (how to play live webm stream)

Tags: google-chrome, ffmpeg, html5-video, webm, ffserver

I have webm streams coming from an ffserver (16 streams), managed to get all 16 to load at once within a browser, but whether I am playing just one or 16 there is a delay of 3-5 seconds introduced due to either buffering or the handshake plus some kind of compensation to try and sync the timestamps by the browser itself, which leads to my question:

Is it possible to force a browser playing a webm stream via HTML5's video tag (I only really care about Chrome, but it's happening in Firefox too) to play from the actual most recent frame (clients and servers share a common NTP server over the LAN, so they are guaranteed to be synced, if that is a factor) as opposed to maintaining a buffer of several seconds and playing from the start of that buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to change you ffserver config file settings. I also have a series of pipe images and probably add the following parameters to your config file might decrease the delay.

PreRoll 0

StartSendOnKey

Comment: Since noone else has responded I'll go ahead and mark this correct since you say it might work - no idea if it works though (switched to a proprietary CCTV system so don't have the ffserver running for it anymore).